# group by in django aggregate function?

Tags: sql, django, group-by, aggregate

I have problem writing group by sql into django app. Can any of you django users help me how to write this sql into django-friendly code? This is my model:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Stock's name", max_length=200)
    symbol = models.CharField("Stock's symbol", max_length=20)

class Dividend(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField('pay date')
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)

class UserStock(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField('amount', default=0)
    date = models.DateField('buy date')
    price = models.FloatField('price', default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
```

And this is sql code I want to write in django:

```
select stock_id, sum(price), sum(amount) as price from stocks_userstock group by stock_id;
```

I was trying to write something like this.

```
my_stock = UserStock.objects.filter(user=request.user)\
    .annotate(sum_price = sum('price'), sum_amount = sum('amount'))
```

Thanks in advance, I hope it won't be a problem for some of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe just adding a `values` call will do that

```
my_stock = UserStock.objects.get(user=request.user)\
    .values('stock_id').annotate(sum_price = sum('price'), sum_amount = sum('amount'))
```

and you will get back a list of dicts similar to

```
[
    {'stock_id': 0, 'sum_price': 10, 'sum_amount': 25},
    ...
]
```

see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for more info

Comment: It still gives me same error as before. `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` on line `.values("stock_id").annotate(sum_price = sum('price'), sum_amount = sum('amount'))`. Those data from db should be int, why is it string?

Comment: I don't know, you never mentioned an error before... Are you using the proper `Sum`? (it should be capital, I was just using what you posted)

Comment: Yep, it was sum with small first letter. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucas03 Just change it to `.values('stock_id', 'id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
stock = Stock.objects.all().annotate(sum_price = Sum('user_stock__price'), sum_amount = Sum('user_stock__amount'))
```

It should work.

I've removed the `User` filter in my snippet to simplify but you can add it of course.